# pytorch derivative returns none on .grad

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

```
i1 = tr.tensor(0.0, requires_grad=True)
i2 = tr.tensor(0.0, requires_grad=True)
x =  tr.tensor(2*(math.cos(i1)*math.cos(i2) - math.sin(i1)*math.sin(i2)) + 3*math.cos(i1),requires_grad=True)
y =  tr.tensor(2*(math.sin(i1)*math.cos(i2) + math.cos(i1)*math.sin(i2)) + 3*math.sin(i1),requires_grad=True)
    
z = (x - (-2))**2 + (y - 3)**2
z.backward()
dz_t1 = i1.grad
dz_t2 = i2.grad
print(dz_t1)
print(dz_t2)
```

im trying to run the following code, but im facing an issue after `z.backward()`. `i1.grad` and `i1.grad` return none. from what i understand the cause of this issue is with the way `backward()` is evaluated in torch. so something along the lines of `i1.retain_grad()` has to be used to avoid this issue, i tried doing that but i still get none. i1.retain_grad and `i2.retain_grad()` were placed before `z.backward()` and after `z.backward()` and i still get none as an answer. whats happening exactly and how do i fix it? `y.grad` and `x.grad` work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
i1 = tr.tensor(0.0, requires_grad=True)
i2 = tr.tensor(0.0, requires_grad=True)
x =  2*(torch.cos(i1)*torch.cos(i2) - torch.sin(i1)*torch.sin(i2)) + 3*torch.cos(i1)
y =  2*(torch.sin(i1)*torch.cos(i2) + torch.cos(i1)*torch.sin(i2)) + 3*torch.sin(i1)
z = (x - (-2))**2 + (y - 3)**2
z.backward()
dz_t1 = i1.grad
dz_t2 = i2.grad
print(dz_t1)
print(dz_t2)
```

Here, using `torch.sin` and `torch.cos` ensures that the output is a torch tensor that is connected to `i1` and `i2` in the computational graph. Also, creating `x` and `y` using `torch.tensor` like you did detaches them from the existing graph, which again prevents gradients from flowing back through to `i1` and `i2`.